# Cast varchar as date select distinct top 100

Tags: select, casting, sql-server-2012, varchar

I am trying to fix a query that has come to light in SSRS after the new year. We have an input that comes from another application. It grabs a date and stores it as `varchar`. The SSRS report then fetches the top 100 'dates' but when 2017 dates have come around, this are not in the top 100.

The existing query is as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100)
FROM DenverTempData
ORDER by BY Date DESC
```

The date is stored as `VARCHAR`. So obviously this query doesn't grab a value such as `01012017` as being a top 100 (over values likes 12312016). I thought maybe I can simply change the datatype on this column to `datetime`. But the information comes from a flat file and is converted, so it's a little more difficult that that. So I'm hoping to do a select of the distinct top 100 while converting the date column to `datetime` or just date and grabbing the last 100 dates.

Can someone help with the query syntax? I'm thinking a cast to convert `varchar` to `date`, but how do I format with distinct top 100? I'm simply looking to retrieve the last 100 dates in chronological order from a column that is stored as `varchar` but contains a string representing a `date`.

Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Are you asking how to change the value to date format like `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: I am asking how to format a select query on a varchar column while converting it to a date data type and selecting the top 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a bad idea to store a date as string. This is highly culture specific!

You can cast your formatted string-date to a real date like this:

```
DECLARE @DateMMDDYYYY VARCHAR(100)='12312016';

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,STUFF(STUFF(@DateMMDDYYYY,5,0,'-'),3,0,'-'),110)
```

After the conversion your sorting (and therefore the `TOP 100`) should work as expected.

My strong advise: Try to store your dates in a column of a real date type to avoid such hassel!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 100 (CAST(VarcharColumn as Date) as DateColumn)
FROM TABLE
Order by DateColumn desc
```

Comment: using SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 (CAST(Date as Date)) as DATE FROM DenverTempData ORDER BY Date desc returns the following error "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: @LONG, There is no direct cast from `12312016`. You can cast a string of format `20161231` (so called *unseparated*), but the string given is `mmddyyyy`... This will not be casteable directly. Even with the appropriated separators `12-31-2016` a cast (or a simple `CONVERT`) would depend on the system's culture settings... In such cases you should call `CONVERT` always together with the appropriate format code, to avoid intercultural problems...